# Can't get android-maven-plugin to recognize SDK path

Tags: android, maven, sdk, apk, android-maven-plugin

I've tried every advertised method to specify the path to my Android SDK when trying to build an Android app using the android-maven-plugin, and nothing works. No matter what I do, when I run

`mvn clean install`

I get

`... Could not find tool 'aapt'. Please provide a proper Android SDK directory path as configuration parameter <sdk><path>...</path></sdk> in the plugin <configuration/>. As an alternative, you may add the parameter to commandline: -Dandroid.sdk.path=... or set environment variable ANDROID_HOME.`

I set env variable ANDROID_HOME to point to the root directory of the SDK, and exported it. Then

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
    <configuration>
        <sdk>
            <path>${env.ANDROID_HOME}</path>
            <platform>19</platform>
        </sdk>
        ...
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

does not work. (and I have API 19 installed in the SDK)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
    <configuration>
        <sdk>
            <path>/absolute/path/to/sdk</path>
            <platform>19</platform>
        </sdk>
        ...
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

does not work

```
 <properties>
         <android.sdk.path>/absolute/path/to/sdk</android.sdk.path>
 </properties>
```

Does not work. And

```
mvn clean install -Dandroid.sdk.path=/absolute/path/to/sdk
```

Does not work.

I've also tried appending the tools, platform-tools, and build-tools/19.1.1 directories in the SDK to $PATH, and this does not work either. The aapt tool is available on my path, but the maven plugin refuses to see it. I searched the web, and the only advice I see is to do what I've done.

What am I missing? I'm doing this on an OSX system.

Comment: What look like your `ANDROID_HOME`? What android-maven-plugin version?

Comment: I think the plugin version is the issue. I was using 3.1.1, from an example I grabbed rfom the web. I tried 3.8.2, the latest, and I have to upgrade from maven2 to maven3. Will do that now and report back, but it's probably the problem.

Comment: Yes, for sure, older android-maven-plugins are not compatibile with new android SDK.

Comment: Actually I have maven 3.0.5, and I need to upgrade to 3.1.1

Comment: ***Prerequisites**: Maven 3.1.1+ installed* :)

Comment: That fixed the problem, thanks! Version 3.8.2 of android-maven-plugin and maven 3.1.1 was the right incantation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older versions of Android Maven Plugin might not work with latest SDK. For example support for SDK 22 was added in version 3.6.0. Check [changelog](http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/changelog.html).

> **3.6.0**
>
> The plugin has been updated to work with the SDK release 22.0. 21.1 works on the CI server. It might or might not work for older versions.

You don't need to configure `ANDROID_HOME` inside pom.xml, my working configuration looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.2</version>

    <configuration>
        <sdk>
            <platform>19</platform>
        </sdk>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Configure `ANDROID_HOME` properly, for me this points to

```
.../adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/
```

Make sure it is properly configured, before invoking maven. For example simply run `echo $ANDROID_HOME`

Comment: Thanks. I believe that's exactly what I'm doing. Configuring ANDROID_HOME inside the pom was just one of several things I tried when doing what I thought was the right thin wasn't working. I have ANDROID_HOME pointing to the rood directory of the android sdk. I verify it with echo before invoking maven.

Comment: @MidnightJava What is the version of `android-maven-plugin`? Execute maven build with -X and post full error.

Comment: Per answer given in OP: Version 3.8.2 of android-maven-plugin and maven 3.1.1 was the right incantation.

Comment: Changelog now here http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/changelog.html